# ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer is not refreshing properly

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server

I have a DynamicMapServiceLayer that I am refreshing every 30 seconds. I want the data in the map to refresh every 30 seconds too but it doesn't appear to be working properly.

The map refreshes but then the service goes away and I just see a blank map. The service will stay off for about 20 seconds then come back on again. My code is here too...Is there a way to keep the service on all the time and still refresh it or make it so it doesn't go away?

Thanks in advance!

```
var map;
    require(["esri/map", "dojo/domReady!", "esri/layers/ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer"], function (Map, domReady, ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer) {
        map = new Map("mapDiv", {
            center: [-56.049, 38.485],
            zoom: 2,
            basemap: "streets"
        });
        var liveLayer = new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("http://server/MapServer", 
        { 
            refreshInterval: .5,
            disableClientCaching: true
        });
        console.log(liveLayer);

        map.addLayers([liveLayer]);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<!--The viewport meta tag is used to improve the presentation and behavior of the samples 
  on iOS devices-->
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"/>
<title></title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.8/js/dojo/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.8/js/esri/css/esri.css">
<style> 
  html, body { height: 100%; width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
  #map{
    padding:0;
  }
</style> 

<script src="http://js.arcgis.com/3.8/"></script>
<script> 
  var map;
  require([
    "esri/map", "esri/dijit/BasemapGallery", "esri/layers/ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer", "esri/arcgis/utils",
    "dojo/parser",

    "dijit/layout/BorderContainer", "dijit/layout/ContentPane", "dijit/TitlePane",
    "dojo/domReady!"
  ], function(
    Map, BasemapGallery, ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer, arcgisUtils,
    parser
  ) {
    parser.parse();

    map = new Map("map", {
      basemap: "topo",
      center: [-105.255, 40.022],
      zoom: 13
    });

    //add the basemap gallery, in this case we'll display maps from ArcGIS.com including bing maps
    var basemapGallery = new BasemapGallery({
      showArcGISBasemaps: true,
      map: map
    }, "basemapGallery");
    basemapGallery.startup();

    basemapGallery.on("error", function(msg) {
      console.log("basemap gallery error:  ", msg);
    });
    var liveLayer = new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Demographics/ESRI_Population_World/MapServer", 
    { 
        opacity: .5,
        refreshInterval: .5,
        disableClientCaching: true
    });
    console.log(liveLayer);

    map.addLayers([liveLayer]);

  });
</script> 
</head> 

<body class="claro"> 
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/BorderContainer" 
     data-dojo-props="design:'headline', gutters:false" 
     style="width:100%;height:100%;margin:0;">

  <div id="map" 
       data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" 
       data-dojo-props="region:'center'" 
       style="padding:0;">

    <div style="position:absolute; right:20px; top:10px; z-Index:999;">
      <div data-dojo-type="dijit/TitlePane" 
           data-dojo-props="title:'Switch Basemap', closable:false,  open:false">
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" style="width:380px; height:280px; overflow:auto;">
        <div id="basemapGallery" ></div></div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
</body> 

</html>
```

It works fine and every 30 sec refresh the map correctly.